# A type-definition rule to detect missing properties in repeating objects (e.g. multi language fields)

Tags: typescript, type-definition

Imagine I have a type definition like:

```
export type TextMessagesType = {
  [language: string]: {
    [placeholder: string]: string;
  };
};
```

That would fit in this case:

```
export const TextMessages: TextMessagesType = {
  en: {
    noText: 'No Texts available!',
  },
};
```

Now, if I want to add new languages and new properties like:

```
export const TextMessages: TextMessagesType = {
  en: {
    noText: 'No Texts available!',
    welcome: 'You are welcome'
  },
  de: {
    noText: 'Keine weiteren Texte vorhanden!',
    // welcome missing
  },
};
```

I would like to ensure that the `de`-object has exactly the same properties as the `en`-object. The IDE should recognize the missing properties (e.g., `welcome`) due to type-definitions.

Can I do that with the assistance of typescript type definition rules? If yes, how?

**EDIT:** Excuse me, I think, an important information is missing:

The recognizing-mechanism should work **dependent on existing properties** in each object. Imagine `de` object has a property `xy` and it is missing in the `en` object and vice versa. If a language object gets a new property it should be marked in all other language objects as a missing property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a union type of strings to achieve this, with the `in` keyword on the type of the key:

```js
type RequiredLanguageFields = 'welcome'
  | 'noText';

type TextMessagesType = {
  [language: string]: {
    [placeholder in RequiredLanguageFields]: string;
  };
};

const TextMessages: TextMessagesType = {
  en: {
    noText: 'No Texts available!',
    welcome: 'You are welcome'
  },
  de: {   // type error on this line
    noText: 'Keine weiteren Texte vorhanden!',
    // welcome missing
  },
};
```

> Property 'welcome' is missing in type '{ noText: string; }' but required in type '{ welcome: string; noText: string; }'.(2741)

It's a slight bit of extra work in that you need to define the required fields before you add them to the object. Alternatively you could have some master translation object and use the keys of that to define the required keys of the others:

```js
const enStrings = {
  noText: 'No Texts available!',
  welcome: 'You are welcome',
};

type TextMessagesType = {
  [language: string]: {
    [placeholder in keyof typeof enStrings]: string;
  };
};
```

---

Based on the edit to your question, I'll attempt to describe why I believe it won't be possible to create a type in the way you're looking to do it.

Now we're saying that all values must be objects of the same type - they must all have the same properties and all of those properties must be strings. But what is that type? We might define some interface which takes a generic:

```js
interface ITextMessagesType<T> {
  [language: string]: {
    [placeholder in keyof T]: string;
  };
};

const TextMessages: ITextMessagesType = {    // error here as we have no passed in the type for the generic `T`
  en: {
    noText: 'No Texts available!',
    welcome: 'You are welcome'
  },
  de: {   // type error on this line
    noText: 'Keine weiteren Texte vorhanden!',
    // welcome missing
  },
};
```

We still need to define what that generic is; we're back to the problem you have with the original example I gave above - you need to define the keys before defining the object.

It's a little easier in a function, as we can infer the type from the object passed in. But then we're onto the next issue; which object is treated as the required type? Take the following code as an example:

```js
const test = <T>(x: { [key: string]: { [key in keyof T]: string } }) => true;

const x = test({
  en: {
    noText: 'No Texts available!',
    welcome: 'You are welcome',     // now we get a type error here
  },
  de: {
    noText: 'Keine weiteren Texte vorhanden!',
    // welcome missing
  },
})
```

The error that we get is:

> Type '{ noText: string; welcome: string; }' is not assignable to type
>   '{ noText: string; }'.   Object literal may only specify known
>   properties, and 'welcome' does not exist in type '{ noText: string;
>   }'.(2322)

Here Typescript has determined that the value at `de` is the 'master' type - and as such in gives an error where we've tried to define the `welcome` key on `en`.

As such I don't believe you'll be able to get what you're asking for - hopefully someone will come in and prove me wrong.

Comment: Thank you, Oliver, but the recognizing-mechanism should work dependent on existing properties in each object. Imagine `de` object has a property `xy,` and it is missing in the `en` object and vice versa. Excuse me for my imprecise question, I've made an addition.

Comment: @Lonely Ok sure - I've updated the answer; I'm fairly sure that you can't type this in Typescript, though I hope I'm proved wrong

Comment: thank you very much Oliver, I came to the same conclusion but  I was very uncertain because I'm not an type-expert yet.

Comment: @Lonely I'm forever suprised by what is possible in typescript so you may yet find it possible to get a good type on this - fingers crossed!

Comment: Would you suggest a better title for my question?

Comment: @Lonely I believe there's enough for a separate question; I've asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62303746/define-a-type-for-an-object-where-all-values-have-the-same-type)

Comment: @Lonely I'd update the answer with the content of the other question, but I can't seem to get it working for an interface or type ha