# Define a type for an object where all values have the same type

Tags: typescript, types, rules, type-definition

I'm trying to define a type for an object, such that every value of the object has the same type, and must have the same keys. I'd like to be able to do this where every value has the same keys, defined as the union of the types of all the values.

```js
const test = {
  a: {               // I'd like to see a type error on this line
    x: 1,
  },
  b: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
  },
}
```

It's possible when you define the type in advance:

```js
interface IA {
  [key: string]: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
  }
}

const test: IA = {
  a: {         // now we get a type error because we don't have y on this object
    x: 1,
  },
  b: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
  },
};
```

I can get something close with code like this:

```js
const test = <T>(x: { [key: string]: { [key in keyof T]: string } }) => true;
```

Alternatively, in a function we can infer the type, but then the problem is that it doesn't take a union of all the types, but only the first in the object:

```js
const test = <T>(x: { [key: string]: { [key in keyof T]: number } }) => true;

const x = test({
  a: {
    x: 1,
  },
  b: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,            // now we get a type error here
  },
})
```

The type error here is:

> Type '{ x: number; y: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ x:
>   number; }'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and
>   'y' does not exist in type '{ x: number; }'.

I don't really see how this can be done in typescript, and I suspect it isn't possible - does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with the second code sample? Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: You want the error to move to the property with less keys rather than on the property with more keys ? This might be close enough: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=10&pln=11&pc=53#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwNIRAZwDwwHxQC8sUEAHsBHACaYkD8UA1hkgGYkBcUcEAbhABOAbgBQogMYpMwKJRlEo2ACp4AFGW7KoAMigAlCFMHVsLEOyjKANAaNITuRCnRYVAbXOXlAXTy24AFcAWwAjITw8AEoiAmBBQIgxSWlZMkV5YDUAb1EoKABDblz8-M0oAEZrPKgAX2r80OKasu4qlqgQbgAmBrrq2qigA

Comment: Dear @MikeS, If the properties are dynamically created, you cannot create a list in advance, because you don't know them yet.  Every property (a,b,..) should have the same number, name, and same type of elements. That's is a very complicated use case: Imagine a user makes an additional change in a language and forgets to update other languages. That should be recognized automatically.

Comment: @MikeS. Sorry if that wasn't clear; I want the error on the value of `a` because its value is not of the type of the union of all the values. The value on `b` _is_ of the type of the union the all the values, though, so should have no error

Comment: Dear @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I think, that's the right answer and a great answer, would you add it here? Thank you very much!

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir This solves the problem exactly - excellent!

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I've added your answer here, fyi kind rgds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great answer from @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwNIRAZwDwwHxQC8sUEAHsBHACaYkD8UA1hkgGYkBcUcEAbhABOAbgBQogMYpMwKJRlEo2ACp4AFGW7KoAMigAlCFMHVsLEOyjKANAaNITuRCnRYVAbXOXlAXTy24AFcAWwAjITw8AEoiAmBBQIgxSWlZMkV5YDUAb1EoKABDblz8-M0oAEZrPKgAX2r80OKasu4qlqgQbgAmBrrq2qigA):

```
type UnionKeys<U> = U extends U ? keyof U : never;

const test = <T>(x: T & Record<keyof T, Record<UnionKeys<T[keyof T]>, number>>) => true;

const x = test({
  a: {
    x: 1,
  },
  b: {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
  },
})
```

Comment: That's not a check of property names, but it helps very much,..